# Input string was not in a correct format, Drop down list Selected Value

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down list with a button, when the button is clicked, a separate class is called for a function to run a SQL stored procedure that inserts a row in a table. However, when the button is clicked, I get a FormatException error.

```
    protected void btnAssignWork_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            RequestBO requestBO = new RequestBO();
            int oppid = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Opportunity"]);
            int EmpId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlRadWorkers.SelectedValue);
            requestBO.AssignOpportunity(EmpId, oppid);

    }



       private void FillRadWorkerDDL()
    {
        RequestBO requestBO = new RequestBO();
        DataSet dsRADWorkers = null;
            dsRADWorkers = requestBO.GetRadWorkers();
            ddlRadWorkers.DataSource = dsRADWorkers;
            ddlRadWorkers.DataTextField = "EmpName";
            ddlRadWorkers.DataValueField = "EmployeeID";
            ddlRadWorkers.DataBind();
            ddlRadWorkers.Items.Insert(0, "Select Employee");
    }
```

Fill Rad Worker is called on page load, and RequestBO.GetRadWorkers returns 2 columns, EmployeeID and EmpName. When the button is clicked, the Employee ID and Opportunity ID should be fed to the stored procedure, but the FormatException stops this.

Any guidance is appreciated

UPDATE: Was a post back issue sorry guys, the value was coming through incorrect because ASP.NET wasn't picking up on the new value of the DDL

Comment: Are you sure the error is not raised at this line `int oppid = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Opportunity"]);`?

Comment: Is it possible for you to print the content of Request.QueryString["Opportunity"] to a label (or use breakpoints if they work in your environment) to make sure it is a value that can be converted to int?

Comment: Where do you get the exception ? on query string line or the other one ?

Comment: Double check that your query string contains `Opportunity` key, I feel that it could be `OpportunityId` :)

Comment: It would really help to know where the exception is thrown. Please update your question :-)

Comment: int EmpId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlRadWorkers.SelectedValue);

Is the line with the exception

Comment: Was a post back issue, sorry guys :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to see/print the values of both `Request.QueryString["Opportunity"]` and `ddlRadWorkers.SelectedValue`. You did not tell at which line it throws exception, if it comes at `Convert.ToInt32(ddlRadWorkers.SelectedValue);` then probably you did not correctly set the data source of `ddlRadWorkers`. Set it like this:

```
private void FillRadWorkerDDL()
{
    ...
    ddlRadWorkers.DataSource = dsRADWorkers.Tables[0];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Opportunity"].ToString()) and 
int EmpId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlRadWorkers.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling Convert.ToInt32(string str) you should do the following:

```
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
   {
       Convert.ToInt32(str);
   }
```

Or you can use int.TryParse. This method returns a boolean value instead of throwing an exception, and returns the integer value in an output parameter. The benefit of using TryParse is that you will also prevent your code from throwing an exception, in case the string has other characters than numbers

Answer (score 0):

Yes problem might be due to post back, I also got the same problem ,and stuck for many hours for similar problem  but as soon as I put ispostback  in page load fucntion enclosing FillRadWorkerDLL() function declaration, the problem got solved.
Try doing this .

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        FillRadWorkerDLL();
    }
}

FillRadWorkerDDL(){ //your code here }
```

Suggestion: 
1)Try using debugging mode (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>) on that `FillRadWorkerDLL();` line and try to solve it.